# Execute Stored Procedure NHibernate and return DTO/entity mapped without unique key

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, dto

I have a class and a simple stored procedure like in the following code. The problem is I want to use NHibernate to execute the stored procedure and return a DTO / entity (mapped without unique key). Does anybody have idea? Please help me. Thank you

```
public class Dto
{
    public virtual int DeptId { get; set; } 
    public virtual int EmpId { get; set; }  
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}

// mapping without id => because the stored procedure returns 
// results that do not have unique column 
public class DtoMap : ClassMapping<Dto>
{
    public DtoMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.EmpId, m => m.Column("emp_id"));  // if emp_id is PK and I use Id here,  it is ok. But in my case it is impossible
        Property(x => x.DeptId);
        Property(x => x.Name, m => m.Column("name"));
   }
}
```

Simple code is used to query using NHibernate with correct configuration

```
var list = session.GetNamedQuery("GetAll").List<Dto>();
```

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetAll]
AS 
   SELECT  
       employeeid as emp_id, deptid, name 
   FROM 
       Employee; -- the query can not change
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not map `Dto` in this case. I'd alter your named query mapping:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="false">
  <sql-query name="GetAll">
    <return-scalar column="emp_id" type="int" />
    <return-scalar column="deptid" type="int" />
    <return-scalar column="name" type="string" />
    exec dbo.[GetAll]
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And then just use a `Transformer` when executing your query:

```csharp
var list = session.GetNamedQuery("GetAll")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Dto>())
    .List<Dto>();
```

Another option would be to use LINQ to project the results:

```
var list = session.GetNamedQuery("GetAll")
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(o => new Dto 
        { 
            EmpId = (int)o[0],
            DeptId = (int)o[1], 
            Name = o[2].ToString()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I thought about this but in your case, the properties of dto must be named exactly the name of return columns i.e. emp_id, depid

Comment: @Martinez: I didn't know that was the case--I'll do some digging and see if I can improve the answer

Comment: @Martinez: I updated my answer. I don't think you have many options since NHibernate requires some kind of unique identifier.